# Display DB blob type in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, http, flex4, flash-builder

My Mysql database stores images (in PNG, JPG)of our personnel and it's field type is set to longblob.

Is there any possibility to load blob data type using HttpService and render it in Image component in Flex .??? ^..^

I'm eager to know about as it comes in handy in the nearest future!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but I don't see the point of storing your images in a DB.

Simplest way to get it into an Image is to load the blob, convert to a ByteArray which you can set as the source of of said Image.

Comment: i have them already in my mysql db stored, I just want to display them!

Comment: more info `http://www.phpriot.com/articles/images-in-mysql/2` `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527801/php-to-store-images-in-mysql-or-not`

Answer (score 1):

If you override HttpService you can use it to receive binary data. If you don't want to override HttpService you have the option of encoding you binary data in [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) before sending it.

But if have the option to store the images in a directory on the server and just send links to the client - that would be a better solution.