# How to add photo in mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to PHP and I need your help.

This is insert.php file that inserts all records.``
File browsing field is also added here. This field browse photo. Temp_File is stored in thumbnails folder. My Question is how to save this photo in MySQL database and how to retrieve this photo from dB for displaying in view.php.

//This is insert.php

```
    <?php require_once('Connections/db_sms.php'); ?>
    <?php if (!isset($_SESSION)) {


    session_start();
    }
    $MM_authorizedUsers = "";
    $MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";

    // *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
    function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
      // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
      $isValid = False; 

      // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
      // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
      if (!empty($UserName)) { 
        // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
        // Parse the strings into arrays. 
        $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
        $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
        if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
          $isValid = true; 
        } 
        // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
        if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
          $isValid = true; 
        } 
        if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
          $isValid = true; 
        } 
      } 
      return $isValid; 
    }

    $MM_restrictGoTo = "login.php";
    if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers,      $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
      $MM_qsChar = "?";
      $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
      if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
      if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
      $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
      $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
      header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
      exit;
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
    {
      if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
        $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
      }

      $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

      switch ($theType) {
        case "text":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;    
        case "long":
        case "int":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "double":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "date":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;
        case "defined":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
          break;
      }
      return $theValue;
    }
    }

    $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
      $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    }

    if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "regform")) {
      $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_student (s_id, first_name, last_name, gender, dob, father_name, email, address, city) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['student_photo'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['first_name'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['last_name'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['gender'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['dob'], "date"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['father_name'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['address'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['city'], "text"));

      mysql_select_db($database_db_sms, $db_sms);
      $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $db_sms) or die(mysql_error());

      $insertGoTo = "view.php";
      if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
        $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
        $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
      }
      header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
    }
    ?>
    <?php require_once('Zend/Date.php'); ?>
    <?php $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $host = "localhost";
    $database = "db_sms";

    // Make the connect to MySQL or die
    // and display an error.
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    if (!$link) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    // Select your database
    mysql_select_db ($database);?>


    <?php if (isset($_FILES['student_photo']) && $_FILES['student_photo']['size'] > 0) { 

              // Temporary file name stored on the server
              $tmpName  = $_FILES['student_photo']['tmp_name'];  
              // Create the query and insert
              // into our database.
              $i=rand(0,8888);
               $info=pathinfo($_FILES['student_photo']['name']);
                $ext=$info['extension'];
                $i++;
                $newname="pic_".$i.".".$ext;
                $target='thumbnails/'.$newname;
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES['student_photo']['tmp_name'], $target );
              $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_students ";
              $query .= "(student_photo) VALUES ('$data')";
              $results = mysql_query($query, $link);

              // Print results
              print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded.";

    }
    else {
       print "No image selected/uploaded";
    }


    mysql_close($link);
    ?>


    <?php
    if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 




    {
      if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
        $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
      }

      $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

      switch ($theType) {
        case "text":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;    
        case "long":
        case "int":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "double":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "date":
           if ($theValue == "")
          {
              $theValue = "NULL";
          }
          else
          {
              $zendDate = new Zend_Date($theValue, "d/M/yyyy");
              $theValue = "'" . $zendDate->toString("dd-MM-yyyy") . "'";
          }
          break;
        case "defined":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
          break;
      }
      return $theValue;
    }
    }

    mysql_select_db($database_db_sms, $db_sms);
    $query_rsStudent = "SELECT s_id, first_name, last_name, gender, dob, father_name, email, address, city, student_photo FROM tbl_student ORDER BY first_name ASC";
    $rsStudent = mysql_query($query_rsStudent, $db_sms) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rsStudent = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsStudent);
    $totalRows_rsStudent = mysql_num_rows($rsStudent);

    $query_rsStudent = "SELECT first_name, last_name, gender, dob, father_name, email, address, city FROM tbl_student ORDER BY first_name ASC";
    $rsStudent = mysql_query($query_rsStudent, $db_sms) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rsStudent = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsStudent);
    $totalRows_rsStudent = mysql_num_rows($rsStudent);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Registration</title>

    <script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationRadio.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationRadio.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body,td,th {
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #636;
        margin-left: 400px;
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-right: 400px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php /* include('include/header.php');*/ ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" name="regform" id="regform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

    <table width="1495" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="115">First Name</td>
        <td width="1370"><span id="spryfirstname">
        <input name="first_name" type="text"    maxlength="50" />
        <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td><span id="sprylastname">
        <input name="last_name" type="text"    maxlength="50" />
        <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td><label>
        <span id="spryrggender">
        <input  type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="male" />
    Male<br />
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="female" />
    Female<br />
    <span class="radioRequiredMsg">Required.</span></span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Date Of Birth</td>
        <td><span id="sprydob">
        <input name="dob" type="text"   />
        <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Date of Birth is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Father's Name</td>
        <td><span id="spryfathername">
        <input name="father_name" type="text"  maxlength="50" />
        <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>E-mail Address</td>
        <td><span id="spryemail">
        <input name="email" type="text"   />
        <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span><span class="textfieldMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td><span id="spryaddress">
        <input name="address" type="text"  />
        <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>City</td>
        <td><span id="sprycity">
          <input name="city" type="text"  />
          <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Upload image</td>
        <td>
          <input type="file" name="student_photo" id="student_photo" />
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input name="insert" type="submit" value="Insert Record" /></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="regform" />
    </form>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("spryfirstname", "none", {validateOn:["blur"], maxChars:50});
    var sprytextfield2 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprylastname", "none", {validateOn:["blur"], maxChars:50});
    var spryradio1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationRadio("spryrggender", {validateOn:["blur"]});
    var sprytextfield3 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprydob", "date", {format:"dd/mm/yyyy", validateOn:["blur"], hint:"dd/mm/yyyy"});
    var sprytextfield4 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("spryfathername", "none", {validateOn:["blur"], maxChars:50});
    var sprytextfield5 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("spryemail", "email", {maxChars:50, validateOn:["blur"]});
    var sprytextfield6 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("spryaddress", "none", {maxChars:50, validateOn:["blur"]});
    var sprytextfield7 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprycity", "none", {maxChars:50, validateOn:["blur"]});
    var sprytextfield8 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield8");
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    mysql_free_result($rsStudent);
    ?>


-----------------------------------------------------
//Image should be displayed in view.php

<?php require_once('Connections/db_sms.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
  $isValid = False; 

  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 
  return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "login.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
  exit;
}
?>
<?php require_once('Zend/Date.php');?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$currentPage = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];



$maxRows_rsStudent = 3;
$pageNum_rsStudent = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_rsStudent'])) {
  $pageNum_rsStudent = $_GET['pageNum_rsStudent'];
}
$startRow_rsStudent = $pageNum_rsStudent * $maxRows_rsStudent;

mysql_select_db($database_db_sms, $db_sms);
$query_rsStudent = "SELECT s_id, first_name, last_name, gender, dob, father_name, email, address, city, student_photo FROM tbl_student ORDER BY first_name ASC";
$query_limit_rsStudent = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_rsStudent, $startRow_rsStudent, $maxRows_rsStudent);
$rsStudent = mysql_query($query_limit_rsStudent, $db_sms) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsStudent = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsStudent);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_rsStudent'])) {
  $totalRows_rsStudent = $_GET['totalRows_rsStudent'];
} else {
  $all_rsStudent = mysql_query($query_rsStudent);
  $totalRows_rsStudent = mysql_num_rows($all_rsStudent);
}
$totalPages_rsStudent = ceil($totalRows_rsStudent/$maxRows_rsStudent)-1;

$queryString_rsStudent = "";
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  $newParams = array();
  foreach ($params as $param) {
    if (stristr($param, "pageNum_rsStudent") == false && 
        stristr($param, "totalRows_rsStudent") == false) {
      array_push($newParams, $param);
    }
  }
  if (count($newParams) != 0) {
    $queryString_rsStudent = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));
  }
}
$queryString_rsStudent = sprintf("&totalRows_rsStudent=%d%s", $totalRows_rsStudent, $queryString_rsStudent);
?>

<?php


if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
       if ($theValue == "")
      {
          $theValue = "NULL";
      }
      else
      {
          $zendDate = new Zend_Date($theValue, "M/d/yyyy");
          $theValue = "'" . $zendDate->toString("yyyy-MM-dd") . "'";
      }
        break;

    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}
?>
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    color: #000;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 18px;
}
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #606;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #066;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #600;
}
</style>

<body bgcolor="#D6D6D6" text="#FFFFFF" link="#330000" vlink="#006666" alink="#660000"><h1>
  <style type="text/css">
#header {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    color: #066;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: url(../images/contest.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    margin-bottom: 400px;
}
body,td,th {
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    color: #000;
}
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
  </style>
</h1>
 <?php /* include('include/header.php');*/?> 

<h3>&nbsp;</h3>
<h3>There are <?php echo $totalRows_rsStudent ?> Students.</h3>
<p>&nbsp;
  <?php if ($pageNum_rsStudent > 0) { // Show if not first page ?>
    <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_rsStudent=%d%s", $currentPage, 0, $queryString_rsStudent); ?>">First</a> <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_rsStudent=%d%s", $currentPage, max(0, $pageNum_rsStudent - 1), $queryString_rsStudent); ?>">Previous</a>
    <?php } // Show if not first page ?>
  <?php if ($pageNum_rsStudent < $totalPages_rsStudent) { // Show if not last page ?>
  <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_rsStudent=%d%s", $currentPage, min($totalPages_rsStudent, $pageNum_rsStudent + 1), $queryString_rsStudent); ?>">Next</a> <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_rsStudent=%d%s", $currentPage, $totalPages_rsStudent, $queryString_rsStudent); ?>">Last</a>
  <?php } // Show if not last page ?>
</p>
<table width="400" border="0">

</table>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="2139" border="0">

    <tr>
      <th width="326" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col"><strong>First Name</strong></th>
      <th width="315" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col"><strong>Last Name</strong></th>
      <th width="282" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col"><strong>Gender</strong></th>
      <th width="183" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col"><blockquote>
        <p> <strong>BirthDate</strong></p>
      </blockquote></th>
      <th width="337" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col"><strong>Father's Name</strong></th>
      <th width="271" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col"><strong>Email</strong></th>
      <th width="95" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col"><strong>Address</strong></th>
      <th width="150" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col"><strong>City</strong></th>
      <th width="150" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col"><blockquote>
        <p>Photo</p>
      </blockquote></th>
      <th width="150" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
      <th width="7" bgcolor="#009999" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
      <th width="131" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
     <?php do { ?>
   <?php 
            $zendDate = new Zend_Date($row_rsStudent['dob']);
          ?>

    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#333333"><blockquote>
        <p><a href="update.php?s_id=<?php echo $row_rsStudent['s_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rsStudent['first_name']; ?></a></p>
      </blockquote></td>
      <td bgcolor="#333333"><blockquote>
        <p><?php echo $row_rsStudent['last_name']; ?></p>
      </blockquote></td>
      <td bgcolor="#333333"><blockquote>
        <p><?php echo $row_rsStudent['gender']; ?></p>
      </blockquote></td>
      <td bgcolor="#333333"> 
          <?php echo $zendDate->toString("d/M/yyyy"); ?></td>
      <td bgcolor="#333333"><blockquote>
        <p><?php echo $row_rsStudent['father_name']; ?></p>
      </blockquote></td>
      <td bgcolor="#333333"><blockquote>
        <p><?php echo $row_rsStudent['email']; ?></p>
      </blockquote></td>



      <td bgcolor="#333333"><blockquote>
        <p><em><strong><a href="delete.php?s_id=<?php echo $row_rsStudent['s_id']; ?>"></a></strong></em><?php echo $row_rsStudent['address']; ?></p>
      </blockquote></td>
      <td bgcolor="#333333"><blockquote>
        <p><em><strong><a href="delete.php?s_id=<?php echo $row_rsStudent['s_id']; ?>"></a></strong></em><?php echo $row_rsStudent['city']; ?></p>
      </blockquote></td>
      <td bgcolor="#333333"><blockquote>
        <p><img src="<?php echo "thumbnails/".$row_rsStudent['student_photo']; ?>"/> </p>
      </blockquote></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><blockquote>
        <p><em><strong><a href="delete.php?s_id=<?php echo $row_rsStudent['s_id']; ?>">Delete</a></strong></em></p>
      </blockquote></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_rsStudent = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsStudent)); ?>
  </table>
  <p><strong><a href="insert.php">Insert New Record</a></strong></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
<?php
mysql_free_result($rsStudent);
?>
```

---

//the tbl_student contains a field name "std_photo" with type VarChar(255).

---

//This is my db_sms connection file

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_db_sms = "localhost";
$database_db_sms = "db_sms";
$username_db_sms = "root";
$password_db_sms = "";
$db_sms = mysql_pconnect($hostname_db_sms, $username_db_sms, $password_db_sms) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

---

HELP ME PLEASE!

Comment: My advice would be not to store the image in the database at all. I've never seen a good reason to do this when a file system is perfect for this. store the location of the file instead.

Comment: Please, post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), your code is incredibly long.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527801/php-to-store-images-in-mysql-or-not

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to keep images in database. The best way to do this, is record the image path in a simple text field. To display it, just perform a simple query to get the image path and print it into the  tag.

Comment: I can think of some reasons. Ease of deployment is one for example.

Comment: And again this uninformed constantly repeated dogma. Please try better and give at least some references.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to store image in MySQL (which may not be a good idea) you should use BLOB column type. Here is an example http://www.phpriot.com/articles/images-in-mysql

Comment: to add - I would heavily suggest storing the image on a filesystem, and just storing the link to the image in the database

Comment: Completely agreed. Storing as BLOB is just a variant.

Comment: @Ascherer What is your reasoning for this?

Comment: @PeeHaa mysql isnt meant for storing whole objects like that. Extremely inefficient

Comment: @Ascherer Actually it depends whether it is inefficient. And I seriously doubt it is that *extremely* inefficient as you state. Also storing it in the database has some real advantages (besides some disadvantages).

Comment: @PeeHaa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472233/can-i-store-images-in-mysql

What advantages are there exactly?

Comment: Besides ease of deployment, imho thats not an advantage over the database performance...

Comment: MySQL has a BLOB data type which is indeed exactly meant for storing binary data like images. The performance impact is if existing esoteric. Do realistic benchmarks or please post references if you state different. Advantages are e.g. having ACID, not to cope with distributed transactions, keeping the code simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than store the image itself in the d/b it is better to store the image on the disk as a file. Store $target (from  $target='thumbnails/'.$newname;) as a string - and when viewing it use the retrieved $target to construct am image tag

Comment: Croves got there before me!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $tmpName  = $_FILES['student_photo']['tmp_name'];  
              // Create the query and insert
              // into our database.
              $i=rand(0,8888);
               $info=pathinfo($_FILES['student_photo']['name']);
                $ext=$info['extension'];
                $i++;
                $newname="pic_".$i.".".$ext;
                $target='thumbnails/'.$newname;
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES['student_photo']['tmp_name'], $target );
              $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_students ";
              $query .= "(student_photo) VALUES ('$data')";
              $results = mysql_query($query, $link);
```

// In between these lines, you should save the image name & path into your database.

For example: `mysql_query("UPDATE from SET image_path='$image' WHERE id='12')")`
You can use also, `INSERT` but, the $name should include path also like 
`$name = thumbnails/$newname` the id should be relative, to the row of the post you are making in the database.

```
          // Print results
          print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded.";
```

In view.php you can simple show the image when you are showing the post/article at the same time. Ex:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM students";
$result = mysql_query();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
`echo "
Student Name: $row['student_name'] <br/>
Student Photo: $row['image_path']
"`
}
```

The above will search from database, the student along the image.