# Move_uploaded_foto to the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, upload

```
if ($count == 1){
    $suc= move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $destin.$file_name);
    echo"<br/>";
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO login ( profile_img) VALUES ('$file_name')  WHERE useremail='".$_SESSION["sess_useremail"]."'") 
       or die("cant  still upload ".mysql_error());
}
```

How can i save image into the database?

Comment: You need to base64 encode your image to insert it into a databsae.

Answer (score 0):

try this links [How to upload images into MySQL database using PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717506/how-to-upload-images-into-mysql-database-using-php-code)   and [How to add photo in mysql database using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729308/how-to-add-photo-in-mysql-database-using-php)