# Update mysql XML blob

Tags: mysql, windows-7, mysql-workbench

I am working on a Windows 7 machine and need to update a mySql row on an Ubuntu server. I open Workbench and run "show grants;" and it returns with GRANT ALL

I have a column in the database that shows as xml in the Workbench viewer when I run:select UNCOMPRESS(data) from database.detail where file_id = 57;

I need to update that row, I tried to save the blob as xml on disk and run: select LOAD_FILE('C:\Trash\544357.xml'); but that returns nothing so: UPDATE database.detail SET data = LOAD_FILE("C:\Trash\544357.xml") where file_id = 57; does not work either.

Comment: did you try ``\\``? `C:\Trash` will probably just be parsed as `C:Trash` by MySQL, since \T isn't a valid metachar escape

Comment: I did and it made no difference. Even tried to change to /

Answer (score 0):

Rack on up for not reading some of the answers I found on Google!! This [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721317/load-file-returns-null) explained that the file must be on the server. I moved the file from my local windows 7 machine to the Ubuntu mysql box tmp folder and ran: UPDATE database.detail SET data = LOAD_FILE("/tmp/544357.xml") where file_id = 57

DONE!!!